# Под категории на Yii2 не получается сделать что бы при выборе под категории выводилось пустое поле

Tags: php

Делаю под категории на yii если нужно добавляем под категорию если нет тогда пустое поле (создаю первую категорию и потом эта категория появляется)

Названия категории 
выбор категории из выпадающего списка 
статус (опубликован черновик)

структура бд 
category_id
category_name
parent_id
category_status

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'category_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'category_id', 'category_name')) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'category_status')->dropDownList(['0' => 'Черновик', '1' => 'Опубликован']) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Как сделать так что бы при нажатие на выбор категории первым выпадало пустое поле.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `<?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'category_id', 'category_name'),  ['prompt'=>' ']) ?>`

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую